# impicit Ordering and covariance

Tags: scala, implicit

```
class Foo
class Bar extends Foo
implicit val ord = new math.Ordering[Foo] {
  override defcompare(a: Foo, b: Foo) = 0
}
```

When trying to summon the Ordering instance of Bar

```
implicitly[math.Ordering[Bar]]
```

it fails with

```
No implicit Ordering defined for Bar.
```

I expected it to pick up the instance I defined on Foo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via @Daunnc:

```
implicit def ord[A <: Foo] = new math.Ordering[A] { override def compare(a: A, b: A) = 0 }
```

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is, [`math.Ordering[T]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.math.Ordering) is invariant on `T` and so a `math.Ordering[Foo]` has no relation to a `math.Ordering[Bar]` even though `Bar` is a subclass of `Foo`.

You can provide an implicit factory for `Ordering[T]` instances to work around this, as @DaunnC points out in the comments:

```
implicit def ord[A <: Foo] = new math.Ordering[A] {
  override def compare(a: A, b: A) = 0
}
```

Comment: Is it reasonable to implement my own implicit `Ordering`, which would be covariant and convert it to `math.Ordering`?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, as I know `scalaz` has `Order`, that, seems to me, works as expected (contra-variant).

Comment: @Reactormonk oh, I see. It is possible to define ordering as a generic function (lil bit ugly workaround). `implicit def ord[A <: Foo] = new math.Ordering[A] { override def compare(a: A, b: A) = 0 }` your sample with implicit should work.

Comment: @Daunnc we got a winner.